# Peculiar Behavior After Reboot and Clearing Workspace Possibly Related to R and RStudio Updates

Tags: r, shiny

I recently upgraded to R version 4.0.2 and RStudio 1.3.1056 and believe that may be at the root of this problem.  After copying a section of my Shiny code to create a minimal reproducible example (mprex), I get an error for a section of code that's not in the mprex.  I cleared my RStudio workspace and rebooted both my computer and RStudio, but continue to get the same error.

Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- (fluidPage
       (
         fileInput("sessionFileName", "Session File Name")
       )
)

# Define server logic
server <- (function(input, output, session)
{
  
  inputParameters <- reactive ({
    if (is.null(input$sessionFileName)) return
    inFile <- input$sessionFileName
    if (!is.null(inFile)) {
      inputData <- readRDS(file=inFile$name)
    }
    inputIDs      <- names(inputData) 
    inputvalues   <- unlist(inputData) 
    for (i in 1:length(inputData)) {
      print (paste(inputIDs[i],inputvalues[[i]],sep=' '))
      session$sendInputMessage(inputIDs[i],  list(value=inputvalues[[i]]) )
    }
  })
})
  
# Start the shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here's the error I get when I try to run my code:

```
Error in reqHistoricalData(tws, twsEquity(equity), yesterday4PM, backtestFrequency,  : 
  could not find function "reqHistoricalData"
```

It's pretty clear the error has nothing to do with the code I'm trying to run.  I realize my code may have other errors. The error appears when I launch my code.  My guess is that someone running this code on a different machine would not get the same error, but I don't know yet if that's true.

Here's the startup banner when I start an RStudio session.

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Workspace loaded from ~/Library/MobileDocuments/com~apple~CloudDocs/r Dev/.RData]
```

For this last line of the startup banner, "[Workspace loaded from ~...]", I don't understand if there's a way for me to delete and/or reset the workspace that's being loaded.  Perhaps that's the solution to this problem.

I do have many packages in my environment, including IBrokers, to which this error refers.  I've been running other Shiny scripts that access the function **reqHistoricalData()**.

Is this a bug in either Shiny and/or R?  Any ideas about how to get this code to run?

Comment: I can confirm this error does not occur on my machine at least, and I _seriously_ doubt it will occur on anyone else's computer with the code you've posted---I would be shocked if it did. Can I ask if you use the `IBrokers` package at all, and have you run the command before that is described in the error (`reqHistoricalData(...)`)?

Comment: It would be useful to see the last few lines of the startup banner, i.e. what comes after `Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.`  This will appear in the console window when you start RStudio.

Comment: RStudio is just an IDE, it could not have any bearing on the code or what R does in this case. My sense is that you have other things running that involve a package that hasn't been reinstalled after updating R to v4.0.2.

Comment: @duckmayr I do use the IBrokers package.  And yes, I had run the reqHistoricalData() function some time in the same session before creating the mprex.

Comment: @user2554330 I did include the startup banner in the post and it does show the workspace was loaded from a particular file.  But the file must be hidden.  Should I just delete the workspace file?

Comment: @SNovogoratz I probably would delete it, though it may not be necessary. You can change your RStudio options to not restore saved workspaces on start up (Tools > General, it will be under "Workspaces" -- uncheck "Restore .RData into workspace at startup"), or if you're running R from the command line, run it with "R --no-restore"

Comment: The filename `.RData` is hidden by default, which makes it a little harder to delete than most files.  But from the terminal app you could run `rm ~/Library/MobileDocuments/com~apple~CloudDocs/r Dev/.RData` to delete it.  Should you?  I'd say probably yes.  You'll lose whatever was saved there, but it sounds as though you don't want that stuff anyway.  In general, it's a good idea to set the RStudio option to never save the workspace: `Preferences | General | Save workspace to .RData on exit:  never`

Comment: @duckmayr Yes, that was it.  I removed the .RData file and unchecked the "Restore .RData into workspace" parameter to resolve the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2554330 Yes, thank you.  I removed the .RData file and reset the RStudio preference to never save the .RData file.  And it worked.